# jquery ajax get/post to a javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ok, so the following is what I want to achieve:

I want to use jquery to load a file inside my javascript file.
Normaly you can do a `$.ajax` request with a `POST` to a `.php` file. And select something in a database that looks like the `POST` I sended with. Now I want the same thing, but instead using a `.php` file, I will use a `.js` file.

This also works, the code loads the file with the text `alert('Hello World!');` and shows the alert. All fine. But what I want when I load that `.js` file, it needs to send a value with it. So it could be `alert(data);` and it will say hello world. How can i achieve this without using cookies or something else that stores values.

Comment: You can't send data to a JS file as it has no method of retrieving it from the request.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan isn't there a work-around for my problem?

Comment: Not really, no. You could set your server to process JS files, but this is equivalent to just making a request to a PHP page and arguably less secure.

Comment: And what if I request a php file, with javascript code in it. Could that create some problems when importing it using $.ajax?

Comment: No, that would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this a GET request, a POST request is not allowed. Unless you're using GET variables to rewrite your javascript file before returning it you can't modify it or make it do anything other than what would happen if you just requested it with the `<script>` tag with the `async` attribute. /edit

Well I just learned something new. You can get a javascript file with an ajax call and execute it using `eval` but I'm almost 100% certain this is not how you should be doing whatever you're trying to do (also - [when is JavaScript's eval() not evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil))

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/script',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (response) {
        eval(response.toString());
    };
});
```

You're calling the server, which then returns the javascript file and you're parsing it as javascript using `eval`. I never considered doing this but I supposed it's one way to load a javascript file on demand.